Docker container set to wrong port
I'm building an API usign PHP Laravel and chose docker to do run the server. For some reason, it set the port to be 0.0.0.80, which actually is only allowing me to acces the container through the 127.0.0.1 port at the browser. I couldn't find any helpful tip online to change the container's port because my 'ports' variable at the dockerfile receives ports as lists:
    ports:

        - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'

        - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'

If anyone knows how to help I'd be glad to hear.
Laravel v = 11.7, I'm already using Docker's latest version.
I attemped  changing the ports content to something such as ${APP_PORT:-51}:73 so it would match the the port which docker chose for the laravel.test container, but I guess it has nothing to do with the actual api port. It did ruined the connection to the react app I've made to consume this api so I know it's an important field.

Please post questions that are a minimal repro of your issue rather than snippets. Snippets requires us to try to guess what you're doing. The statement ${APP_PORT}:-80}:80 means that, if the environment variable APP_PORT is set, its value will be used as the host (!) port mapping to the container's port (80). If APP_PORT is unset, the default value 80 (on the host) will be used. So, sett APP_PORT or replace the statement with your desired host port (X -- replacing X with an actual port value) X:80.

Same-same for VITE_PORT except this environment variable must be used within the container too to set the host and container port to the same value.

ports:

        - '${APP_PORT:-8181}:80'

or add APP_PORT=8181 or any port you want
and then run sail down and then sail up -d
